# Matrix Notation Clarification

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

From the book: Introduction to High-Dimensional Statistics by Christophe Giraud.

[image]

What is meant by the notation of $X^{(i)}$?  Is the subscript notation $X_i$ meant to be the variable and the superscript notation $X^{(i)}$ is the entire $i^{th}$ vector of the $X$ matrix?

Comment: Context makes it  clear that  $X^{(i)}$ means  the $i$-th vector.  It's $j$-th component would be something like $X_j^{(i)}$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why it is a vector though.  The book states that there are n i.i.d. observations $(Y_i,X^{(i)}) so that would mean the observations would be one single y from Y and a whole column vector of X.  Does it mean row vector of X rather than a column vector?

Comment: Each $X$ vector has $p$ components.  There are $n$ different values of $i$ and so $n$ different $X^{(i)}$ vectors, each with its corresponding $Y_i$ value.  This is the standard set up in regression analysis.

Comment: The book notation, however, has $(Y_i,X^{(i)}) $ so the "i's" have to be the same.  So We can't have something like $(Y_1,X^{(2)}) $

Comment: I don't think I said anything of the sort.  The $i$-th $Y$ value, $Y_i$ is associated with vector $X^{(i)}$ which according to the displayed formula is an element of $[0,1]^p$, that is, of a $p$-tuple.  There is, if you will, a rectangle of predicting values, the $i$-th row and $j$-th column holds the $j$-th component of the $i$-th vector.

Comment: That helps out a lot!  Thank you very much, kimchi lover.